# Is this transaction approach REST-ful?

Tags: rest

Simplification of my use-case but I want to create a REST service for processing customer orders.

In RPC world I would create a RPC endpoint

```
OrderProduct(CustomerID, ProductID, Quantity)
```

This would

- Create an orders DB record
- Decrement available stock on a Product DB
  record
- Create an entry in a Worklist table for stockpicking

(Not my real use-case but more understandable than what I'm doing)

In my REST approach I already have POST endpoints for Customer, Product and Worklist, but I now need to combine calls to all 3 in a single transaction.  My problem is having the ability to rollback in the event that the insert into worklist fails for any reason.

So is it appropriate to create a ProductOrder endpoint exposing only POST?

Within the service handling the POST I'd create a DB transaction and interact with the database directly to update the three tables I'm concerned with.

My nervousness is around

1. Not re-using the entity endpoints I've already exposed.
2. Inventing an entity just to handle an RPC type call (and hence only
   implementing POST)

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Well, I am not really sure what the question is... if you want to create an endpoint that uses post for ordering a product that combines the 3 things then I would say that is acceptable.  Just make sure you have a roll back process in case a step failed.  Should be easy enough to do that.  Depending on your DB you could probably do all of this db side, with triggers and sps wrapped in a transaction in case something failed so you can roll it back.  But its very doable code side as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Don't worry! Think in terms of conceptual entities, not RPC. When in doubt, make a new RESTful entity with GET, POST, and optionally PUT and DELETE.

You are mostly correct, you would want a "ProductOrder" endpoint, though I would just call it 'Order'. Since you have an 'Orders' DB record, it makes sense to expose that to the same REST workflow as the other entities in your system.

> Not re-using the entity endpoints I've already exposed.

There is no reason to. A product and customer REST endpoint can't help you create an order because an order itself is a conceptual entity in your system that may encompass many different steps spanning a complicated lifecycle (validating the order, tracking the order status, decrementing stock, transferring funds). Your REST client should not have to know every step, it should only know that creating an Order requires a POST to the Order endpoint.

> Inventing an entity just to handle an RPC type call (and hence only implementing POST)

That's kind of the point. You have an 'Order' entity which you can 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', or 'DELETE' on. The idea would be that you would be able to get a customers total orders by using GET /customers/{id}/orders or get the details about a specific order using /orders/{id} or /customers/{id}/orders/{id} or even create a new order by using POST /customers/{id}/orders.

Order becomes an entity from which you can apply all of the standard RESTful operations on.